# <object> works in every browser except Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, object, xhtml

I have a problem with loading data into an < object > using Javascript. It refuses to work in Chrome, no error message either.

You can see a minimal example to play with here:
http://tinkerbin.com/HIqG0ypb

Comment: Now the MAGIC happens. Click the "Open URL" link in Chrome, confirm the alert and press F12! Still does not answer my question as it is hard to force all Chrome users into pressing F12 like maniacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange to me that browsers assume object.data could be set as *URI* but display *content available at that URI*. It sounds like a security flaw : full content could be injected into a page without using frame. I wonder if test.com in your example has access to window.parent or something like that

[EDIT]

So

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openFrame() {
    document.getElementById('testFrame').data="http://test.com";
  }
</script>
```

Must be written for Chrome as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openFrame() {
    document.getElementById('testFrame').data="http://test.com";
    var el = document.getElementById("testFrame");
    var h = el.innerHTML;
    el.innerHTML = h;
  }
</script>
```

where testFrame is :

```
  <object id="testFrame" type="text/html" style="overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%" />
```

Comment: This happens independent of the actual URL being used. I used a local html page in the same directory and it still does not work. I don't see why it shouldn't work, see w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Comment: Yup, looks like the data frame can access windows.parent. But it could as well just break out of the frame traditionally.

Comment: strangely, document.getElementById("testFrame") in chrome console returns null

Comment: I ran your sample and saw nothing. then, browsing dom tree using chrome dev tools, test.com appeared when i clicked on "testFrame" html child

Comment: Yes, I was fiddling with the F12 tools as well when it suddenly came up. So it definetely is supported, just not right? At this point I'm nearly convinced to write a bug report.

Comment: It also loads test.com if you ask for page source. definitely weird!

Comment: I am a little bit late to this topic, but is there an JQuery solution for this?