# Cannot refresh <object/> when changing from application/pdf to text/html

Tags: html, typescript, google-chrome

I am trying to refresh an  element in the DOM tree. Basically the typescript code simply update the `data` & `type` of an existing `HTMLObjectElement`. Here is the pseudocode:

```
const textCanvas: HTMLObjectElement = <HTMLObjectElement>(curElement.children.namedItem('text-canvas'));
// Populate both the actual data as well as the associated mime/type:
textCanvas.data = enabledTextElement.textData; // 'blob:http://localhost:8081/d3c9a0ac-8e40-4e0e-aeb8-91656273837c'
textCanvas.type = enabledTextElement.mimeType; // 'application/pdf'
```

Which then gets updated with:

```
textCanvas.data = enabledTextElement.textData; // 'blob:http://localhost:8081/3c5ad888-0a7f-41d0-8ec9-35c334ef3f20'
textCanvas.type = enabledTextElement.mimeType; // 'text/html'
```

My chrome simply display the PDF version:

[image]

The funny part is if I do the opposite (html first), then the  element gets properly updated (html text is displayed, then the PDF box is displayed). I tried to verify if this is supposed to work at:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-object-element

And it seems it should. I also found an old bug report:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123536
- -> [<object> works in every browser except Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245385/object-works-in-every-browser-except-google-chrome)

Using:

```
Google Chrome   80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 81_Win_122)
Revision    e7fbe071abe9328cdce4ffedac9822435fbd3656-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#1037}
OS  Windows 8.1 (Build 9600.19676)
JavaScript  V8 8.0.426.30
```

---

If that help the URL are created from a `Blob` which is then passed to `URL.createObjectURL`.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the following work-around:

```
textCanvas.data = '';
textCanvas.type = enabledTextElement.mimeType;
textCanvas.data = enabledTextElement.textData;
```

Seems to make the symptoms go away. I've filled a bug report just in case:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1076373