# How to modify <object> data attribute for Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome, object

I am trying to change the data attribute of an  element with id 'previewImage'. I modify the attribute by doing an Ajax call to another file, and get back the data. All browsers shows the data received from the AJAX-call (image or PDF) (encoded base64), except Google Chrome. Is there an solution for this?

I saw this answer earlier, but I think it is deprecated (it did not work for me): [<object> works in every browser except Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245385/object-works-in-every-browser-except-google-chrome)

Ajax Call:

```
function getFile(id, r = false)
{
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/project/getFile",
            method: "POST",
            data: {id: id}
        })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $('#previewImage').prop('data', data);
            })
    }, 100)
}
```

object:

```
<object id="previewImage" class="w-100" style="min-height: 500px">
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are using an object for that - and not simply an `img` element?

Comment: Yeah, it is also possible the getFile() method is returning an PDF file. Edited the question to make it clearer!

Comment: What happens when you try `attr` instead of `prop`? Or de-reference your jQuery object to get the native HTMLObjectElement, and then assign the property directly, does that help? I.e., `$('#previewImage')[0].data = data;`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I still the same problem, works for all browsers, except Google Chrome, with both solutions

Comment: Since the object doesn't have the data attribute initially, try `.attr()` or dereference as CBroe suggested: `$('#previewImage')[0].setAttribute('data', data)`. Once the attribute is establish treat it as a property `.prop()` and `[0].data =`. jQuery is strict with this attribute/property relationship, JS not so much.

Comment: Does it work if you put a Data URI into the object's `data` attribute directly in the HTML source code already? If not, this might be a security restriction, https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/, https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/chrome-data-url-phishing/ (the latter is from 2017, not sure what the current state regarding this is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone! I changed the object tag to an Iframe, witch made the following:

```
<iframe id="previewImage" class="w-100" height="500px"></iframe>
```

The AJAX-call stayed almost the same:

```
function getFile(id, r = false)
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/project/getFile",
                method: "POST",
                data: {id: id}
            })
                .done(function(data)
                {
                    $('#previewImage').prop('src', data);
                    $('#previewImage image').css("width: 100%")
                })
        }, 100)
    }
```

This worked for me!